# Form validation in javascript is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function submitForm() {
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}

function validate() {
  var ValidName = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  var mailformat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$/;
  var ValidAddress = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-]+$/;
  var cityRegex = /^[a-zA-z] ?([a-zA-z]|[a-zA-z] )*[a-zA-z]$/
  var validPostcode = /^[0-9]+$/;
  var ValidMessage = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,'-]+$/;
  var a = document.forms["form1"]["message"].value;

  if (!document.getElementById("username").value.match(ValidName)) {
    alert("Please Enter A Valid First Name");

    return false;
  }

  if (!document.getElementById("password").value.match(ValidName)) {
    alert("Please Enter A Valid Last Name");

    return false;
  }
  alert {"success"};
}

function success() {
  alert("success")
}
```

```html
<form class="login-form" action="#" name="form1" id="form1">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
  <button onclick="validate()">Login</button>
  <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="Register.html">Create an account</a> </p>
</form>
```

the validate function is not working, there is no pop up although I leave the field empty and submit, it just bring me back to the top of the page.

But there is pop up if i change the onclick="validate()" to  onclick="success()", so i guess its not the button's problem. Then what problem is it?

Comment: You have a syntax error here `alert{"success"};` which prevents the whole script from being evaluated. The first thing you should so when you have a problem is to check the console of the browsers developer tools if that one shows any errors - especially syntax errors.

Comment: Besides that to what element should `document.forms["form1"]["message"]` refer?

Comment: @t.niese done fixed the syntax error. the "document.forms["form1"]["message"]" refers to another html file to validate a feedback form. I just simply copy paste the same js file to here and do some adjustment. I deleted that line and it is running properly now!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a little syntax error in your code

```
alert{"success"};
```

should be

```
alert("success");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your if logic is not correct. Also, you cannot use {} bracket with alert. It must be (). Below code works perfectly fine for me (I consider ValidName variable for explanation).

```
    function submitForm() {
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
  }
   function validate() {
    var ValidName = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,30}$/;
   
  
    if (!ValidName.test(document.getElementById("username").value)) {
      alert("Please Enter A Valid First Name");
  
      return false;
    }
  
    if (!ValidName.test(document.getElementById("password").value)) {
      alert("Please Enter A Valid Last Name");
  
      return false;
    }
    success();
  }
  
  function success() {
    alert("success")
  }
```

Comment: `You should not use Not operator with DOM element` where is the `!` used on the DOM element? The only place where the `!`  appears is on the result of the `.match` call.